# How to get column names even if it is NULL in Rcpp?

Tags: r, rcpp

I want to get column names of a matrix to set another one, but if matrix does not have column names (or is set to NULL), the following code crashes my R session.

```cpp
CharacterVector cn = colnames(x);
```

The following code is the way how I get column names of a matrix even if it does not have.

```cpp
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// Get column names or empty
// [[Rcpp::export]]
CharacterVector get_colnames(const NumericMatrix &x) {
   CharacterVector cn;

   SEXP cnm = colnames(x);
   if (!Rf_isNull(cnm)) cn = cnm;

   return(cn);
}
```

Is there a more elegant way?

Comment: Sometimes in life before grabbing something you need to ensure it is there.  Matrices are required to have column names, you are being too aggressive here.  In short, test with attributes first.  Methinks we have examples at the Rcpp Gallery.

Comment: And of course I missed the all-importamt "not" up there: _Matrices are **not** required to have column names._

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had started this and then got distracted. @coatless covered it, this is simply shorter.

#### Code

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::plugins(cpp11)]]
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
CharacterVector getColnames(const NumericMatrix &x) {
  size_t nc = x.cols();
  SEXP s = x.attr("dimnames");  // could be nil or list
  if (Rf_isNull(s)) {           // no dimnames, need to construct names
    CharacterVector res(nc);
    for (size_t i=0; i<nc; i++) {
      res[i] = std::string("V") + std::to_string(i);
    }
    return(res);
  } else {                      // have names, return colnames part
    List dn(s);
    return(dn[1]);
  }

}

/*** R
m <- matrix(1:9,3,3)
getColnames(m)
colnames(m) <- c("tic", "tac", "toe")
getColnames(m)
*/
```

#### Output

```
R> Rcpp::sourceCpp("~/git/stackoverflow/55850510/answer.cpp")

R> m <- matrix(1:9,3,3)

R> getColnames(m)
[1] "V0" "V1" "V2"

R> colnames(m) <- c("tic", "tac", "toe")

R> getColnames(m)
[1] "tic" "tac" "toe"
R>
```

Comment: Thanks Dirk, but returning default column names does not work for me but I've got the point. In my situation, I want to set column names of matrix B if matrix A has column names. So, checking `x.hasAttribute("dimnames")` and `Rf_isNull(dimnames[1])` would be enough if I don't want to use `SEXP`.

Comment: Sure.  Your posted example did not use two matrices so it is a little hard to guestimate what you wanted ...

Comment: Sorry :). What about returning `NULL` (or similar behavior as R) from `Rcpp::colnames` if matrix does not have column names like R's `colnames` function? Do you think to implement something about it in the future?

Answer (score 4):

Few notes:

1. Matrices do not always have `colnames()` or `rownames()` set.

   - If one is set, then the object has the attribute of `dimnames`.
2. It's okay to check for existence of a value via the C API for R.

   - e.g. `Rf_isNull()`.
3. An alternative existence check would be to verify if `dimnames` is part of the attributes for the object.

   - From there, check if the entry in `dimnames` is null.

Let's verify these the first point by first creating a matrix *without* names and then making one *with* names. Finally, we'll introduce a more verbose version of your function that tries to resolve a matrix *without* column names.

#### Matrix construction

So, the traditional matrix construction would be:

```r
x_no_names = matrix(1:4, nrow = 2)

x_no_names
#>      [,1] [,2]
#> [1,]    1    3
#> [2,]    2    4
colnames(x_no_names)
#> NULL
rownames(x_no_names)
#> NULL
attributes(x_no_names)
#> $dim
#> [1] 2 2
```

So, there is no `dimnames` for a matrix created *without* column or row names.

What happens if we assign column or rownames to the attributes?

```r
# Create a matrix with names
x_named = x_no_names
colnames(x_named) = c("Col 1", "Col 2")
rownames(x_named) = c("Row 1", "Row 2")

# View attributes
attributes(x_named)
#> $dim
#> [1] 2 2
#> 
#> $dimnames
#> $dimnames[[1]]
#> [1] "Row 1" "Row 2"
#> 
#> $dimnames[[2]]
#> [1] "Col 1" "Col 2"

# View matrix object
x_named
#>       Col 1 Col 2
#> Row 1     1     3
#> Row 2     2     4
```

Notice: The `matrix` object now has a `dimnames` attribute.

#### Implementing a Check in C++

With our understanding of the `matrix` structure, we can check:

1. Does `dimnames` exist as an attribute on the matrix?
2. Is the second entry in `dimnames` not `NULL`?

Note: This approach will make the original function a bit more verbose. The trade off is the function will avoid having to use a `SEXP` return type.

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

// Get column names or empty
// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::CharacterVector get_colnames(const Rcpp::NumericMatrix &x) {

  // Construct a character vector
  Rcpp::CharacterVector cn;

  // Create a numerical index for each column
  Rcpp::IntegerVector a = Rcpp::seq_len(x.ncol());
  // Coerce it to a character
  Rcpp::CharacterVector b = Rcpp::as<Rcpp::CharacterVector>(a);

  // Assign to character vector
  cn  = b;

  if(x.hasAttribute("dimnames")) {
    Rcpp::List dimnames = x.attr( "dimnames" ) ;

    if(dimnames.size() != 2) {
      Rcpp::stop("`dimnames` attribute must have a size of 2 instead of %s.", dimnames.size());
    }

    // Verify column names exist by checking for NULL
    if(!Rf_isNull(dimnames[1]) ) {
      // Retrieve colnames and assign to cn.
      cn = dimnames[1];
    } else {
     // Assign to the matrix
     colnames(x) = cn;
    }
  } 

  return(cn);
}
```

#### Testing the *C++* variant

Calling the function would now give:

```r
get_colnames(x_no_names)
#> [1] "1" "2"

get_colnames(x_named)
#> [1] "Col 1" "Col 2"
```

The first indicates we are using the generated indices whereas the second indicates were retrieving values.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation.